# While doing autofill with a 10 digit phone number, phone number getting filled with leading zero

Tags: html, google-chrome, autofill

While getting a 10 digit saved phone number in chrome website, it is filled as 11 digit where first number is autofilled as zero
Steps to replicate:

- Navigate to chrome setting
- Search for address
- Create new address and filled phone number as 1234567899
- Now while doing autofill, phone number getting filled with leading zero i.e 01234567899

Can anyone please help me so that leading zero will not come while autofilling

Comment: i also have same problem, i can confirm its a bug, as going to autofill in settings, it dont have leading zero. i reported a problem, by pressing 3 dots->help->report a problem. i insist you to do the same so devs can roll in next fix.